# node.js callback Funtion

Tags: node.js, callback, cryptojs

I would like to receive the result value through the "SHA512crypto" callback function and use it for the value in client.query.
But no matter how hard I try, I only get the undefined value. Please give a solution to the no.js beginner.

```
var SHA512crypto = function (KeyValue, callback) {
    crypto.randomBytes(64, (err, buf) => {
        crypto.pbkdf2(KeyValue, buf.toString('base64'), 97325, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
            //console.log(key.toString('base64'));

            callback(err, key.toString('base64'));
            return;
        });
    });
}

// Socket SignUp Data
var socketSignUp = function (SignUpData, callback) {
    var SignUpSQL = 'insert into userinfo values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)';
    var companyInfoSQL ='update companyinfo set address = $1, company_number = $2, company_phonenumber = $3, Business_license_number = $4 where company_code = $5';
    var companyInfoValues = [SignUpData.address, SignUpData.admin_company_number, SignUpData.admin_phone_number, SignUpData.businessLicense, SignUpData.company_code];
    var LoginInfoSQL = 'insert into logininfo(email, status, company_code) values($1, $2, $3)';
    var LoginInfoValues = [SignUpData.email, "false", SignUpData.company_code];
    var TimeStampNumSQL = 'SELECT timestamp FROM userinfo ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1';

    client.query(TimeStampNumSQL, (err, res) => {
        if (res) {
            var SignUpValues = [res.rows[0].timestamp + 1, SignUpData.admin, SHA512crypto(SignUpData.email), SHA512crypto(SignUpData.password), SignUpData.name, SignUpData.company_code, SignUpData.company_number, SignUpData.phone_number];
            client.query(SignUpSQL, SignUpValues);
            if (SignUpData.admin == "admin") {
                client.query(companyInfoSQL, companyInfoValues);
            }
            client.query(LoginInfoSQL, LoginInfoValues);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `SHA512crypto()` function requres a callback to communicate back its value, but when you go to use it in your `SignUpValues` line of code, you aren't passing a callback at all.

Comment: Is there a good way to get a callback? No matter how hard I look, I have no idea of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to convert to a promise and then you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for multiple asynchronous operations to complete.  In reality, I'd like to convert all these callbacks to promises and clean up the code a lot, but here's a modification with the minimum conversion to promises and some added error handling:

```
var SHA512crypto = function (KeyValue) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        crypto.randomBytes(64, (err, buf) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            crypto.pbkdf2(KeyValue, buf.toString('base64'), 97325, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
                //console.log(key.toString('base64'));
                if (err) return reject(err);
                resolve(key.toString('base64'))
            });
        });
    });
}

// Socket SignUp Data
var socketSignUp = function (SignUpData, callback) {
    var SignUpSQL = 'insert into userinfo values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)';
    var companyInfoSQL ='update companyinfo set address = $1, company_number = $2, company_phonenumber = $3, Business_license_number = $4 where company_code = $5';
    var companyInfoValues = [SignUpData.address, SignUpData.admin_company_number, SignUpData.admin_phone_number, SignUpData.businessLicense, SignUpData.company_code];
    var LoginInfoSQL = 'insert into logininfo(email, status, company_code) values($1, $2, $3)';
    var LoginInfoValues = [SignUpData.email, "false", SignUpData.company_code];
    var TimeStampNumSQL = 'SELECT timestamp FROM userinfo ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1';

    client.query(TimeStampNumSQL, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        if (res) {
            Promise.all([SHA512crypto(SignUpData.email), SHA512crypto(SignUpData.password)])
              .then(([emailCrypto, passwordCrypto]) => {
                  var SignUpValues = [res.rows[0].timestamp + 1, SignUpData.admin, emailCrypto, passwordCrypto, SignUpData.name, SignUpData.company_code, SignUpData.company_number, SignUpData.phone_number];
                  client.query(SignUpSQL, SignUpValues);
                  if (SignUpData.admin == "admin") {
                      client.query(companyInfoSQL, companyInfoValues);
                  }
                  client.query(LoginInfoSQL, LoginInfoValues);
              }).catch(callback);
        }
    });
}
```

It seems like all your `client.query()` command should have callbacks and error handling and it seems like you're not properly sequencing some of them to wait for the first one to finish before running the next one.  But, those are separate issues from the question you asked.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem because of this. Thank you so much.
Callback and error application to client.query() will be considered as we correct the code.